# Java: How to center a button in a layout manager and have it rejust to the center upon resize?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I have a button inside a JPanel with both, a width and a height of 70 and I can only seem to center it while keeping it's size in a null layout. While I want it centered like that when resizing the button will stay at it's exact cords. Is there a better layout that can easily acheive this or am I able to do it in a null layout?

Answer (score 3):

Use GridBagLayout with `anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER, fill=NONE, weightX, weightY=0`

UPDATE:
See e.g. [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Simplestgridbaglayout.htm)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any `anchor` in a GridBagLayout.

Comment: anchor is a property of GridBagConstraints